# Assigning numbers to letters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[This is a a plan of  what i want to do with the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuSs7.png)

This is all I have to offer, I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
input ("What's your name?")
[A,J,S]=1
[B,K,T]=2
[C,L,U]=3
[D,M,V]=4
[E,N,W]=5
[F,O,X]=6
[G,P,Y]=7
[H,Q,Z]=8
[I,R]=9
```

- Input a person’s name
- Calculate their lucky name number using the grid in Figure 1 above
- Display the names
- Display the lucky name number

Comment: Can you provide some code to show any attempts that you may have made? Nobody is going to just flat out do your homework for you.

Comment: @Harrison How did you know that this is homework? Is it wrong for me to help someone with a question like this (assuming I don't know it's homework)?

Comment: @pycoder It looks like a homework question.

Comment: As long as the problem description is an external content it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean "not sure if correct"? The code doesn't run, so it probably isn't correct. Try using a python dictionary to map letters to integers

Comment: Mandatory readings: [ask], [MCVE], [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: This was indeed homework but im in serious need of help, you don't have to write the code just tell me some tips please.

Comment: @Jack First you need to read or watch a tutorial for basic Python programming and look in the documentation for functions as `input`. Just Google it and something useful should come up. Nothing in this code indicates that you've done so, which makes people believe you're trying to pass your homework without putting any of your own effort into it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the input value needs to be assigned to a variable. So instead of doing

```
input ("What's your name?")
```

You should write

```
input_text = input("What's your name?")
```

This will store the user's input to the string variable input_text.

Next, we will need to declare a dictionary to map each letter to its number.

```
alpha_map = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}  # And so on until 'Z'
```

After we have done this, we can iterate through each character of input_text and grab its value from the dictionary.

```
alpha_values = []  # An empty list
for character in input_text:
    alpha_values.append(alpha_map[character])  # Adds each character's value to alpha_values.
```

You can use the sum() function to sum up the list of values.

As for adding up the digits, you could convert the resulting number into a string and convert each character to an int before summing up.

```
total = 0
for character in str(number):
    total += int(character)
```

Note that you will have to strip the input text of any non-alphabetical characters, and capitalize all letters for this program to run - there are already plenty of online documentations explaining how to do this.

Comment: As you're a new user I understand why you want to answer questions like these and get some reputations, but when a question shows no indication of own effort to solve the problem then it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: I see what you mean and agree with you there. But we all had problems like this as a beginner. Also, I believe that I didn't write out the code for him, but corrected his mistakes and gave some possible ideas. @TedKleinBergman

Comment: This isn't a problem for a beginner though, but for someone who haven't done any own effort. Any tutorial for beginners would cover how the input function works and how to assign to variables, which indicates he/she hasn't read or watched any tutorial. It's also a homework assignment so the teacher should have gone through the basics as well. I see no possibility to have errors on every line **and** that doesn't even try to complete more than 20 % of the assignment when tutorials and classes are available.